# String to unique int algorithm

Tags: algorithm

We are trying to implement the following case. We have a invoice table and there is a column which has email address. We want to somehow generate a unique int value from this email address and store that in a separate column. This will be used as a FK and indexed. So what I am looking for is an algorithm for generating ints from strings (please note that the email string should always output the same int so each email address as a unique int representation). We can use a bigint as well

Comment: This has been asked many times before, and the short answer is it's impossible to take an infinite (or relatively infinite) domain (string/varchar) and map it 1:1 with a finite domain (int, bigint).  You need to make compromises on uniqueness or the output  data type.  My suggestion is that you just index on the e-mail address itself.

Comment: I don't see why that would be so, @MarkPeters. Any string they get will be encoded in a finite number of bytes. Just interpret the same bytes as a bigint, and voila, you have a number.

Comment: @Tom: I'm not sure of the exact semantics of bigint.  In Java, BigInteger has variable bit length so that would work (I already have a deleted answer along exactly those lines).  My impression is that bigint in the context of SQL is still bounded (64 bit) and so it represents a finite domain.

Comment: I think the point @MarkPeters is making is that the number of possible email addresses is always going to be > the number of integers of a given length.  For example, if using a 64-bit integer, there are 2^64 possible values.  There are an infinite number of possible email addresses, which is > 2^64.

Comment: @TomZych If you've got an integer type with defined precision (e.g. 32bit), it's trivial to generate 2**32 + 1 different E-Mail adresses, and there goes your uniqueness.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt Tom proposed a bigint, which at least under Java semantics does not have such a defined precision (well technically I suppose it has something ridiculous related to the longest possible String).

Comment: @Tom OP talks about inserting the data into a database and doesn't mention Java.  Are there any infinite-length integral types in the common DBMS's?  I'm not aware of any (but that's not to say there aren't, of course!).  If there are, using it as an index would be no different to using varchar.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Was thinking in terms of general programming language bigints, limited only by memory, not database bigints.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simplest solution is to put the email address into its own table along with an identity/auto_increment type column. Then you can simply carry around that identify field (a standard int), and you don't run into any issues with potential hash collisions, and no hashing overhead.

Comment: +1 Best answer, I think. Why complicate things when the OP hasn't made constraints ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems a simple hashcode (MD5, SHA1, ...) should fit your needs; depending on your RDBMS, you might be able to use built-in packages (e.g. Oracle's dbms_crypto) or have to compute them externally.

Some things to keep in mind:

- convert everything to lower/uppercase before computing the hashcode (so USER@DOMAIN.COM gets the same hashcode as user@domain.com)
- apparently, you have a denormalized schema. It would make more sense to have a separate customer table containing the E-Mail adress; invoice should then contain only a foreign key customer_fk

Comment: @Raze2dust Yes, of course. But the probability for that is very, very small (esp. if using SHA1).

Comment: @FrankSchmitt Some people care about the difference between very, very small probability and impossible...and some don't.

Comment: @Frank Schmitt: Since the question mentions invoices, the people that care are customers, accountants, lawyers, etc. Potential collisions should be enough to disqualify any hashing scheme.

Comment: @Blastfurnace: MD5 and SHA1 collisions are an accepted tradeoff for HTTPS certificates, of which there are far more than most customer-email addresses a single company uses. Usually unless somebody is attacking the system and targeting for a collision this will no happen. Also note that the possibility is influenced by the grammar for email addresses as most collisions will appear for strings outside of the grammar or very long (and hence unusable addresses).

Answer (score 0):

MD5 - gives you a 128-bit integer.  (Admittedly, this is bigger than the `int` datatype in most languages, but you won't get near guaranteed uniqueness with with just 32-bits.)

Comment: OP said he wanted a unique integer; MD5 does not guarantee uniqueness.

Comment: You cannot guarantee unique integers (unless using integers of arbitrary length), since there's an infinite amount of possible E-Mail adresses.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt There's a finite number of email addresses that will actually be used, so we could just index all of them as we see them.

Comment: @Michael: daiscog does not state that MD5 guarantees uniqueness. It states that it gets you **near** guranteed uniqueness.

Comment: Depending on inputs vs outputs, NOTHING "guarantees" uniqueness.

Comment: @ypercube When my comment was made, he was silent on uniqueness and added that bit after my comment.

Comment: @MichaelMcGowan Agreed. But then I'd use a separate E-Mail adress table (or better yet, a customer table) with an integer primary key und just use this primary key.

Comment: @MichaelMcGowan Yes, I edited my post immediately after posting it as I thought that additional comment needed to be made.  I agree with those who have said the best way to go is to properly normalize the schema and use auto-increment fields for primary keys.  But I was trying to address the specific question asked,

Comment: There is **not** an infinite number of email addresses. Each is unique.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can get away with a 64-bit int: the max length of an email address is 254 characters and, in this case where you need to preserve the uniqueness of each, hashing will not do it.

So it seems you are stuck with having to get over this 254-character hurdle. My approach (always the brute force approach for me) would be to take the alphabet of allowable characters in an email address, map those to 6-bit values, and use the map to pack them into a series of words.

Take a look at [**rfc3696**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3696) which deals with email addresses in a way that's actually comprehensible.

Sorry to be of so little help.